# Loaded PyTorch model has a different result compared to saved model

Tags: pytorch

I have a python script that trains and then tests a CNN model. The model weights/parameters are saved after testing through the use of:

```
checkpoint = {'state_dict': model.state_dict(),'optimizer' :optimizer.state_dict()}
torch.save(checkpoint, path + filename)
```

After saving I immediately load the model through the use of a function:

```
model_load = create_model(cnn_type="vgg", numberofclasses=len(cases))
```

And then, I load the model weights/parameters through:

```
model_load.load_state_dict(torch.load(filePath+filename), strict = False)    
model_load.eval()
```

Finally, I feed this model the same testing data I used before the model was saved.

The problem is that the testing results are not the same when I compare the testing results of the model before saving and after loading. My hunch is that due to **strict = False**, some of the parameters are not being passed through to the model. However, when I make **strict = True**. I receive errors. Is there a work around this?

The error message is:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for CNN:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "linear.weight", "linear.bias", "linear 2.weight", "linea r2.bias", "linear 3.weight", "linear3.bias". Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "state_dict", "optimizer".
```

Comment: What is the error message? Can you show the complete error stack trace using `strict=True` which enforces a 1-to-1 match between the model's state and the loaded state dict.

Comment: Missing key(s) in state_dict: "linear.weight", "linear.bias", "linear 2.weight", "linea r2.bias", "linear 3.weight", "linear3.bias". Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "state_dict", "optimizer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading a dictionary containing the state of your model as well as the optimizer's state. According to your error stack trace, the following should solve the issue:

```
>>> model_state = torch.load(filePath+filename)['state_dict']
>>> model_load.load_state_dict(model_state, strict=True)
```

Comment: I get the following error when executing the first line. `KeyError: 'state_dict'`. When I search for keys of the model state I only get the following options, `dict_keys(['model', 'optimizer', 'lr_scheduler', 'max_accuracy', 'epoch', 'config'])`

Comment: Then your model state dictionnary is probably store with the key `'model'`, take a look inside it and see!