# Pytorch model results different on each run, when using strict = False when loading weights

Tags: python, pytorch

I am attempting to use an opensource pretrained model (Resnet50) from the following repository https://github.com/ViTAE-Transformer/RSP/tree/main/Scene%20Recognition for scene classification. However when I load the weights I am forced to set `strict = False` to avoid with the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ResNet:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "conv1.weight", "bn1.weight", "bn1.bias", "bn1.running_mean", "bn1.running_var", "layer1.0.conv1.weight", "layer1.0.bn1.weight", "layer1.0.bn1.bias", "layer1.0.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn1.running_var", "layer1.0.conv2.weight", "layer1.0.bn2.weight", "layer1.0.bn2.bias", "layer1.0.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn2.running_var", "layer1.0.conv3.weight", "layer1.0.bn3.weight", "layer1.0.bn3.bias", "layer1.0.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn3.running_var", "layer1.0.downsample.0.weight", "layer1.0.downsample.1.weight", "layer1.0.downsample.1.bias", "layer1.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "layer1.0.downsample.1.running_var", "layer1.1.conv1.weight", "layer1.1.bn1.weight", "layer1.1.bn1.bias", "layer1.1.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn1.running_var", "layer1.1.conv2.weight", "layer1.1.bn2.weight", "layer1.1.bn2.bias", "layer1.1.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn2.running_var", "layer1.1.conv3.weight", "layer1.1.bn3.weight", "layer1.1.bn3.bias", "layer1.1.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn3.running_var", "layer1.2.conv1.weight", "layer1.2.bn1.weight", "layer1.2.bn1.bias", "layer1.2.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn1.running_var", "layer1.2.conv2.weight", "layer1.2.bn2.weight", "layer1.2.bn2.bias", "layer1.2.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn2.running_var", "layer1.2.conv3.weight", "layer1.2.bn3.weight", "layer1.2.bn3.bias", "layer1.2.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn3.running_var", "layer2.0.conv1.weight", "layer2.0.bn1.weight", "layer2.0.bn1.bias", "layer2.0.bn1.running_mean", "layer2.0.bn1.running_var", "layer2.0.conv2.weight", "layer2.0.bn2.weight", "layer2.0.bn2.bias", "layer2.0.bn2.running_mean", "layer2.0.bn2.running_var", "layer2.0.conv3.weight", "layer2.0.bn3.weight", "layer2.0.bn3.bias", "layer2.0.bn3.running_mean", "layer2.0.bn3.running_var", "layer2.0.downsample.0.weight", "layer2.0.downsample.1.weight", "layer2.0.downsample.1.bias", "layer2.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "layer2.0.downsample.1.running_var", "layer2.1.conv1.weight", "layer2.1.bn1.weight", "layer2.1.bn1.bias", "layer2.1.bn1.running_mean", "layer2.1.bn1.running_var", "layer2.1.conv2.weight", "layer2.1.bn2.weight", "layer2.1.bn2.bias", "layer2.1.bn2.running_mean", "layer2.1.bn2.running_var", "layer2.1.conv3.weight", "layer2.1.bn3.weight", "layer2.1.bn3.bias", "layer2.1.bn3.running_mean", "layer2.1.bn3.running_var", "layer2.2.conv1.weight", "layer2.2.bn1.weight", "layer2.2.bn1.bias", "layer2.2.bn1.running_mean", "layer2.2.bn1.running_var", "layer2.2.conv2.weight", "layer2.2.bn2.weight", "layer2.2.bn2.bias", "layer2.2.bn2.running_mean", "layer2.2.bn2.running_var", "layer2.2.conv3.weight", "layer2.2.bn3.weight", "layer2.2.bn3.bias", "layer2.2.bn3.running_mean", "layer2.2.bn3.running_var", "layer2.3.conv1.weight", "layer2.3.bn1.weight", "layer2.3.bn1.bias", "layer2.3.bn1.running_mean", "layer2.3.bn1.running_var", "layer2.3.conv2.weight", "layer2.3.bn2.weight", "layer2.3.bn2.bias", "layer2.3.bn2.running_mean", "layer2.3.bn2.running_var", "layer2.3.conv3.weight", "layer2.3.bn3.weight", "layer2.3.bn3.bias", "layer2.3.bn3.running_mean", "layer2.3.bn3.running_var", "layer3.0.conv1.weight", "layer3.0.bn1.weight", "layer3.0.bn1.bias", "layer3.0.bn1.running_mean", "layer3.0.bn1.running_var", "layer3.0.conv2.weight", "layer3.0.bn2.weight", "layer3.0.bn2.bias", "layer3.0.bn2.running_mean", "layer3.0.bn2.running_var", "layer3.0.conv3.weight", "layer3.0.bn3.weight", "layer3.0.bn3.bias", "layer3.0.bn3.running_mean", "layer3.0.bn3.running_var", "layer3.0.downsample.0.weight", "layer3.0.downsample.1.weight", "layer3.0.downsample.1.bias", "layer3.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "layer3.0.downsample.1.running_var", "layer3.1.conv1.weight", "layer3.1.bn1.weight", "layer3.1.bn1.bias", "layer3.1.bn1.running_mean", "layer3.1.bn1.running_var", "layer3.1.conv2.weight", "layer3.1.bn2.weight", "layer3.1.bn2.bias", "layer3.1.bn2.running_mean", "layer3.1.bn2.running_var", "layer3.1.conv3.weight", "layer3.1.bn3.weight", "layer3.1.bn3.bias", "layer3.1.bn3.running_mean", "layer3.1.bn3.running_var", "layer3.2.conv1.weight", "layer3.2.bn1.weight", "layer3.2.bn1.bias", "layer3.2.bn1.running_mean", "layer3.2.bn1.running_var", "layer3.2.conv2.weight", "layer3.2.bn2.weight", "layer3.2.bn2.bias", "layer3.2.bn2.running_mean", "layer3.2.bn2.running_var", "layer3.2.conv3.weight", "layer3.2.bn3.weight", "layer3.2.bn3.bias", "layer3.2.bn3.running_mean", "layer3.2.bn3.running_var", "layer3.3.conv1.weight", "layer3.3.bn1.weight", "layer3.3.bn1.bias", "layer3.3.bn1.running_mean", "layer3.3.bn1.running_var", "layer3.3.conv2.weight", "layer3.3.bn2.weight", "layer3.3.bn2.bias", "layer3.3.bn2.running_mean", "layer3.3.bn2.running_var", "layer3.3.conv3.weight", "layer3.3.bn3.weight", "layer3.3.bn3.bias", "layer3.3.bn3.running_mean", "layer3.3.bn3.running_var", "layer3.4.conv1.weight", "layer3.4.bn1.weight", "layer3.4.bn1.bias", "layer3.4.bn1.running_mean", "layer3.4.bn1.running_var", "layer3.4.conv2.weight", "layer3.4.bn2.weight", "layer3.4.bn2.bias", "layer3.4.bn2.running_mean", "layer3.4.bn2.running_var", "layer3.4.conv3.weight", "layer3.4.bn3.weight", "layer3.4.bn3.bias", "layer3.4.bn3.running_mean", "layer3.4.bn3.running_var", "layer3.5.conv1.weight", "layer3.5.bn1.weight", "layer3.5.bn1.bias", "layer3.5.bn1.running_mean", "layer3.5.bn1.running_var", "layer3.5.conv2.weight", "layer3.5.bn2.weight", "layer3.5.bn2.bias", "layer3.5.bn2.running_mean", "layer3.5.bn2.running_var", "layer3.5.conv3.weight", "layer3.5.bn3.weight", "layer3.5.bn3.bias", "layer3.5.bn3.running_mean", "layer3.5.bn3.running_var", "layer4.0.conv1.weight", "layer4.0.bn1.weight", "layer4.0.bn1.bias", "layer4.0.bn1.running_mean", "layer4.0.bn1.running_var", "layer4.0.conv2.weight", "layer4.0.bn2.weight", "layer4.0.bn2.bias", "layer4.0.bn2.running_mean", "layer4.0.bn2.running_var", "layer4.0.conv3.weight", "layer4.0.bn3.weight", "layer4.0.bn3.bias", "layer4.0.bn3.running_mean", "layer4.0.bn3.running_var", "layer4.0.downsample.0.weight", "layer4.0.downsample.1.weight", "layer4.0.downsample.1.bias", "layer4.0.downsample.1.running_mean", "layer4.0.downsample.1.running_var", "layer4.1.conv1.weight", "layer4.1.bn1.weight", "layer4.1.bn1.bias", "layer4.1.bn1.running_mean", "layer4.1.bn1.running_var", "layer4.1.conv2.weight", "layer4.1.bn2.weight", "layer4.1.bn2.bias", "layer4.1.bn2.running_mean", "layer4.1.bn2.running_var", "layer4.1.conv3.weight", "layer4.1.bn3.weight", "layer4.1.bn3.bias", "layer4.1.bn3.running_mean", "layer4.1.bn3.running_var", "layer4.2.conv1.weight", "layer4.2.bn1.weight", "layer4.2.bn1.bias", "layer4.2.bn1.running_mean", "layer4.2.bn1.running_var", "layer4.2.conv2.weight", "layer4.2.bn2.weight", "layer4.2.bn2.bias", "layer4.2.bn2.running_mean", "layer4.2.bn2.running_var", "layer4.2.conv3.weight", "layer4.2.bn3.weight", "layer4.2.bn3.bias", "layer4.2.bn3.running_mean", "layer4.2.bn3.running_var", "fc.weight", "fc.bias". 
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "model", "optimizer", "lr_scheduler", "max_accuracy", "epoch", "config".
```

When incorporating `strict = False`, the model works however the output is always different for different runs for the same image.

```
res50_state = torch.load("rsp-resnet-50-ckpt.pth") 
res50.load_state_dict(res50_state, strict = False)
```

I found the following stackoverflow ([Loaded PyTorch model has a different result compared to saved model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71308399/loaded-pytorch-model-has-a-different-result-compared-to-saved-model)) post which addresses issue by amending the code to `torch.load("rsp-resnet-50-ckpt.pth")["state_dict"]`, however this doesnt work for me as I get key error `KeyError: 'state_dict'`

When examining the keys I only have access to following `dict_keys(['model', 'optimizer', 'lr_scheduler', 'max_accuracy', 'epoch', 'config'])`

Any idea how I can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `res50_state` with `res50_state['model']` since that is the key that holds the model weight values. So when you do this:

```
res50_state = torch.load("rsp-resnet-50-ckpt.pth") 
res50.load_state_dict(res50_state['model'], strict = False)
```

It should print out:

```
<All keys matched successfully>
```

**NOTE:** When you initialize `ResNet50` model from [this repo](https://github.com/ViTAE-Transformer/RSP/tree/main/Scene%20Recognition) make sure you define the `num_classes` to be `30`:

```
res50 = resnet50(num_classes = 30)
```

Otherwise, you'll see a size mismatch error since default `num_classes` is set to be `51` and the particular [weight file](https://github.com/ViTAE-Transformer/RSP/tree/main/Scene%20Recognition#aid-28) you referred to has the final FC layer with 30 neurons .

Answer (score 1):

You should read what a [state dict](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/what_is_state_dict.html) is. It's a dictionary where the keys map to specific weights in the model, and hte values are the weight parameters.

The file you load appears to be a dictionary with the following keys: `"model", "optimizer", "lr_scheduler", "max_accuracy", "epoch", "config"`. You're not loading a state dict, you're loading something else entirely. There are no weights to be found in the file you are loading.

When you pass `strict=False`, the model will ignore missing weights and instead randomly initialize them. Since all your weights are missing, this means you are loading a new random model every single time. This is why your results are different every time.

If I had to guess, I would say the state dict you're looking for is at `res50_state['model'].state_dict()`, but it's hard to say without further information about what is actually in the file you loaded.

Comment: Thanks, the file is here ... https://github.com/ViTAE-Transformer/RSP/tree/main/Scene%20Recognition 
Its in the Readme under Results & Models / Aid28 / RSP-ResNet-50-E300